# Visual Studio: SQL server object explorer error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-setup

I cannot figure out how to remedy this error when I select the SQL server object explorer.

```
Could not load file or assembly

'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.11 Version=11.1.0.0

Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**** or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have asked on the microsoft forums but I figured people who actually work with this daily may have a better response.  I am a new user with VS so my knowledge is limited. I have updated VS and I have SQL server 2012 installed on this machine.

Thank you in advance for helping me make sense of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the same with VS 2013, maybe the same root problem:

Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.12 Version=12.0.0

I was able to resolve this by getting the most recent version of **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools**.  This is under the tools menu:

Tools >> Extensions and Updates >> Updates

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do, I forgot about this question.